# Drag and Drop nodes within TreeView

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, treeview

I have a treeview with various nodes and want to be able to drag nodes up and down the list of nodes to rearrange them.

I should be able to drop nodes *between* other nodes, showing a little line in between the two nodes that it will end up between while dragging.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: related question probably same answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709581/whilst-using-drag-and-drop-can-i-cause-a-treeview-to-expand-the-node-over-which?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I found that question, and can use it to highlight the node currently being hovered over, but I don't know how to indicate that I am dropping between nodes - whether I just have to paint this myself or if the control has the feature already.