# Expand a Node in TreeView after a DraggedNode stands two seconds over it. C#

Tags: c#, timer, drag-and-drop, treeview, expand

I have a TreeView in my program with the Drag&Drop functionality, and I´m trying to find a way to expand a node after another node (DraggedNode) stands more than 2 seconds over it. I think that the better way is by using a Timer (But I didn´t really understood how to use them). Here is the code that I have.

```
private void treeView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode targetNode;
        TreeNode draggedNode;

        GetDraggedAndTargetNode(e, out targetNode, out draggedNode);

        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

        if (!targetNode.IsExpanded)
        {
            // set a Timer of 2 seconds 
            //System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            //aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            //aTimer.Interval = 2000;
            //aTimer.Enabled = true;
                targetNode.Expand();
        }
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ???
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: See this accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710093/1150698 to a similar question

Answer (score 0):

To access UI elements don't use System.Timers but the plain Windows.Timer like the one from the toolbox!

Move the timer declaration outside the event, so that it can live on.

In its Tick event stop the timer and do your other stuff. To get access to the node that should be expanded you may have to store a reference to it somewhere, too..

```
theTargetNode = null
Timer aTimer = new Timer();

private void treeView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode targetNode;
    TreeNode draggedNode;

    GetDraggedAndTargetNode(e, out targetNode, out draggedNode);

    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

    if (!targetNode.IsExpanded)
    {
        theTargetNode = targetNode;
        // set a Timer of 2 seconds 
        aTimer.Tick += aTimer_Tick;
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void aTimer_Tick(object source, EventArgs)
{
    aTimer.Stop();
    aTimer.Tick -= aTimer_Tick;
    if (theTargetNode != null) theTargetNode.Expand();
}
```

You should also think about stopping the Timer when the user leaves the Tree etc..

Comment: @coloma1984: Good. You may move the inititalization to the `form.Load` and simply start it in the `Dragover` and save the `aTimer.Tick -= aTimer_Tick;`. And you may want to _accept_ the answer ;-)

Comment: I used the StopWatch() class. Besides, there seems to be something missing in your logic. The idea is: if you stand long enough over the __same__ target node then it should expand. If you drag over another node, then the timer should reset.

Comment: I didn't code that part but I mentioned it in my last sentence. So you would want to do an `aTimer.Stop()` in the Leave and an `aTimer.Stop(); aTimer.Start()` in the MouseMove event.